# jQuery - how to increment a value without assigning it to variable

Tags: jquery, increment

I've been looking through questions related to jQuery and increment and none of the answers provide a solution to me as they suggest creating a variable with initial value of 0 in a global scope.

My problem is: There are two cats with `class="cat"` on my page. I need to listen for a click on any of those cats and display a counter of clicks on a particular cat:

```
<div class="cat-1">
    <h2>Micky</h2>
    <p>Number of clicks: <span class="count-display"></span></p>
    <img src="img/kitty.jpg" class="cat" data-counter>
</div>
<div class="cat-2">
    <h2>John</h2>
    <p>Number of clicks: <span class="count-display"></span></p>
    <img src="img/kitty.jpg" class="cat" data-counter>
</div>
```

The below code would serve the role, if the `++` increment could work, but it gives an error.

```
$(".cat").click(function(event) {
    $(event.target).data("counter")++;
    $(event.target).parents().find(".count-display").text($(event.target).data("counter"));
});
```

I tried assigning `$(event.target).data("counter")` to a variable, but then the value of the counter gets reset on each click and because of that, only "1" is ever displayed without counting further. On the other hand, if I create a variable `"count"` in a global scope, it then does not increment the count for each cat individually but it treats the `"count"` value as shared between them. Is there a way to modify my code to get it working?

Here's the current snippet:

```js
    $(".cat").click(function(event) {
     $(event.target).data("counter")++;
     $(event.target).parents().find(".count-display").text($(event.target).data("counter"));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat-1">
        <h2>Micky</h2>
        <p>Number of clicks: <span class="count-display"></span></p>
        <img src="img/kitty.jpg" alt="cat1" class="cat" data-counter>
    </div>
    <div class="cat-2">
        <h2>John</h2>
        <p>Number of clicks: <span class="count-display"></span></p>
        <img src="img/kitty.jpg" alt="cat2" class="cat" data-counter>
    </div>
```

Comment: `$(event.target).data("counter", $(event.target).data("counter")++);` ?

Comment: @AdityaParab unfortunately, I get the same error

Comment: @AdityaParab The error "Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation" should appear on that solution. Better use " + 1" instead of "++" so the error won't appear. And the counter in the HTML needs to be initalized with 0 (data-counter="0")

Comment: @FabianG unfortunately, I checked your solution, if I initialize data-counter="0" it displays only 0 no matter how many times I click. For pure javascript solution I do not initialize data-counter at all, so I assume jQuery should follow the same logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
$(".cat").click(function(event) {
  var num = parseInt($(event.target).data("counter")) || 0;
  $(event.target).data("counter", num + 1);
  $(event.target).parent().find(".count-display").text($(event.target).data("counter"));
});
```

It will correctly increase the number.

**Demo**

```js
$(".cat").click(function(event) {
  var num = parseInt($(event.target).data("counter")) || 0;
  $(event.target).data("counter", num + 1);
  $(event.target).parent().find(".count-display").text($(event.target).data("counter"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat-1">
  <h2>Micky</h2>
  <p>Number of clicks: <span class="count-display"></span></p>
  <img src="img/kitty.jpg" class="cat" data-counter>
</div>
<div class="cat-2">
  <h2>John</h2>
  <p>Number of clicks: <span class="count-display"></span></p>
  <img src="img/kitty.jpg" class="cat" data-counter>
</div>
```

**demo2**

```js
$(".cat").click(function(event) {
  $(event.target).data("counter", (parseInt($(event.target).data("counter")) || 0) + 1);
  $(event.target).parent().find(".count-display").text($(event.target).data("counter"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat-1">
  <h2>Micky</h2>
  <p>Number of clicks: <span class="count-display"></span></p>
  <img src="img/kitty.jpg" class="cat" data-counter>
</div>
<div class="cat-2">
  <h2>John</h2>
  <p>Number of clicks: <span class="count-display"></span></p>
  <img src="img/kitty.jpg" class="cat" data-counter>
</div>
```

Comment: Good attempt and it's working, would do it like this as well. But the question was "how to increment a value without assigning it to variable" and you used a variable.

Comment: @FabianG try look at demo2

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is perfect. I would never come up with that. Now I need to digest why it works this way and without parseInt assigning it to variable did not work. Great lesson! Thank you :)